# UITextView and Keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextview

I have UITextFields and UIText Views on the same view controller. I'm using this:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

    CGFloat midLine = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator = midLine - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION *viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) *viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

    if (heightFraction < 0.0) {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }


    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT *heightFraction);
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT *heightFraction);
    }


    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

To handle the work of the keyboard appearing and disappearing and keeping the textfield visible while typing. I tried adding the UITextView onto these in both the method declaration and in the code with no success. Any ideas what I need to do or am doing wrong? Also, I do have my const declared in my code, the code above works with UITextFields.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Are you using `UITableView` or any kind of `UIScrollView` based control there?

Comment: I do have everything on a UIScrollView as images will be added to the screen so it will have to move to accommodate.

Comment: I am not understanding your question either. Are you attempting to have the keyboard disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `UITextViewDelegate` methods to know when the keyboard appears and move the content.

```
– textViewDidBeginEditing:
– textViewDidEndEditing:
```

Right now you are only implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods. That's why it works for text fields and does not work for text views.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that lol. Thanks Reecon, it worked.

Comment: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is a better tool if all your worried about is the knowing when the keyboard is shown/dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move elements around on the screen and animate them when the keyboard is shown / hidden you are better off listening to the NSNotifications that are sent.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardShown:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDismissed:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

By using NSNotificationCenter you can gain information that isn't available from the textfield delegate methods like keyboard frame size and most importantly (in my opinion) the timing of the textfield animation.  For reference the keys for the userInfo dictionary are listed in the UIWindow documentation.

```
- (void)keyboardShown:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSDictionary *info = [note userInfo];
    NSNumber *duration = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];

    //do you animations here
}
```

Comment: Could you use NSNotificationCenter to perform segues from a UIView that wasn't on a ViewController? I have a slide out menu that is a subclass of UIView and was thinking that NSNotificationCenter would be the way to do that.

Comment: You could though I'm not sure I sure I would go with a solution that is that decoupled from the view controller.  It sounds like your slide out menu is more like a UIControl in which case I might explore the target action pattern (just like UIButton).  NSHipster did a great writeup on this topic http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/.